# How to put conditional in Python list initialization

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following lists

```
poles = [10, 15]
P_D_given_loc_i= np.zeros(40)
```

Then after this I do:

```
P_D_given_loc_i=[(( (i+1) in poles)) for i in range(40) ]
```

and I got *almost* what I want. I got a list in which all positions before the poles are marked as True, and the rest are False.

Well, turns out that is not exactly what I want. What I want is to get 0.0 instead of False and 1.0 instead of True

```
[ 0.0, 0.0 ,........1.0,  0.0.......]
```

My question is, how can I get this by using `if` inside the list initialization.

And a broader question is , how to use conditionals in lists initialization

Comment: This is a list *comprehension*. Python does not have a real concept of initialization: the first time you assign a name is basically the same as any other. Sure, there wasn't any existing thing that the name already referred to, but that doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simpler approach:

```
poles = np.array([10, 15])
P_D_given_loc_i = np.zeros(40)
P_D_given_loc_i[poles] = 1.0     # Either this,
P_D_given_loc_i[poles + 1] = 1.0 # or this depending on how you define poles.
```

But your original approach work work too if you'd cast to float:

```
P_D_given_loc_i = np.array([float(i+1) in poles for i in range(40)])
```

However for much larger arrays this is much slower.